# Style questions using formattable

Tags: r, formattable

I wish to display a dataframe in HTML using the R package formattable. In the table below, how do I add commas to the values, 6100 and 7500? Note I've rounded these values to the nearest hundred.

Also, how do I increase the size of the font and bold the entire Canada row?

```
library(tidyverse)
library(formattable)

target_year = 1980
current_year = 2019

can_target = 20
can2019 = 37

world_target = 6123
world2019 = 7456

can_change <- (can2019 - can_target) / can_target
world_change <- (world2019 - world_target) / world_target

can_world_table <- tibble(
  region = c("Canada", "World"),
  ty = c(can_target, round(world_target, digits = -2)),
  cy = c(can2019, round(world2019, digits = -2)),
  change = percent(c(can_change, world_change), 0)
) %>% 
  set_names(c("", target_year, current_year, "Change"))


can_world_table
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add commas using `formattable` in different ways.

One way is to add to columns as appropriate, using `format` and `big.mark`, for example:

```
ty = c(can_target, format(round(world_target, digits = -2), big.mark = ",")),
cy = c(can2019, format(round(world2019, digits = -2), big.mark = ",")),
```

which would give you this:

```
# A tibble: 2 x 4
  ` `    `1980` `2019` Change    
  <chr>  <chr>  <chr>  <formttbl>
1 Canada 20     37     85%       
2 World  6,100  7,500  22%
```

Then, to increase font size and bold a row, you can create a formatter and apply to that row:

```
lg_bold <- formatter("span", style = ~style("font.weight" = "bold", "font.size" = "16px"))
formattable(can_world_table, list(area(row = 2) ~ lg_bold))
```

One other note is I added a space to row 1, col 1 instead of an empty string, as formattable didn't link that.

```
can_world_table <- tibble(
  region = c("Canada", "World"),
  ty = c(can_target, format(round(world_target, digits = -2), big.mark = ",")),
  cy = c(can2019, format(round(world2019, digits = -2), big.mark = ",")),
  change = percent(c(can_change, world_change), 0)
) %>% 
  set_names(c(" ", target_year, current_year, "Change")) # Added space for formattable

lg_bold <- formatter("span", style = ~style("font.weight" = "bold", "font.size" = "16px"))
formattable(can_world_table, list(area(row = 2) ~ lg_bold))
```

[image: formattable table]

Answer (score 0):

I can answer "add commas to the values" part of your question.

One particular library I've used in the past **numform**.

The end result is of type character, so its useful if you're planning to display the value, but not useful if you're planning to use it in calculations.

```
> library('numform')
> v <- f_comma(c(100000,1000))
> v
[1] "100,000" "1,000"
```

Doco Here: https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/numform/numform.pdf